# Installing Meteor at Koding

Tags: installation, meteor

I'm trying to instal meteor at koding and I got error on the last step `meteor -p port` this is what I get :

```
    app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:33
      throw err;
            ^
Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:1994]
    at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (/Users/chlebta/meteor/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:482:73)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
    at connection.on._self._poolState (/Users/chlebta/meteor/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:96:15)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)
    at Socket.errorHandler (/Users/chlebta/meteor/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:411:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at Socket._destroy.self.errorEmitted (net.js:329:14)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a section about Meteor in the [Koding wiki](http://kwiki.koding.com/wiki/Meteor).

Also, please note that you should select a port inside the port range of `1024` to `10000`. Some ports may be in use, so you might have to try out a few different ones.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've gotten past this, but I had a similar issue. I ended up having to create an environment variable named MONGO_URL:

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://user:pass@host:port/dbname
```

Of course, replace user, pass, host, port and dbname with what Koding assigned to you. Not the most secure, so I'll find a more elegant solution to this, but for the moment, it works.